# Python - convert comma separated string into reducing string list

Tags: python

Given a Python string like this:

```
location_in = 'London, Greater London, England, United Kingdom'
```

I would like to convert it into a list like this:

```
location_out = ['London, Greater London, England, United Kingdom',
                'Greater London, England, United Kingdom',
                'England, United Kingdom',
                'United Kingdom']
```

In other words, given a comma separated string (`location_in`), I would like to copy it to a list (`location_out`) and gradually break it down by removing the first word/phrase each time.

I'm a Python newbie. Any ideas on a good way to write this? Thanks.

Comment: Uh.. Isn't `locaton_out` just `[location_in]`? You need to clarify further.

Comment: don't. I don't know what you are doing but this probably the wrong approach.

Comment: Some great answers below. Thanks everyone for your help!

Comment: @WinstonEwert If you don't know what he is doing, how do you know it is the wrong approach?

Comment: @BenMordecai, the requested output is strange, leading me to think there is probably a better approach to whatever he was trying to do.

Comment: @WinstonEwert I see. I found this question while looking to convert a string `'123, 456, 789'` into a list `['123', '456', '789']` because I am extracting data from MS Excel cells formatted in this manner. I want to make sure I'm not missing something, if in general it's not a good idea.

Comment: @BenMordecai, your example looks sensible. The oddity here is wanting a list of comma-seperated strings. I can't see where that might be helpful.

Comment: @WinstonEwert I see now what you're talking about. He's doing some odd string factorial-esque thing. Sounds like a disconnected theory question that was assigned by a teacher, rather than something which would actually show up in the real world.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

```
location_in  = 'London, Greater London, England, United Kingdom'
locations    = location_in.split(', ')
location_out = [', '.join(locations[n:]) for n in range(len(locations))]
```

Answer (score 1):

Plenty of ways to do this, but here's one:

```
def splot(data):
  while True:
    yield data
    pre,sep,data=data.partition(', ')
    if not sep:  # no more parts
      return

location_in = 'London, Greater London, England, United Kingdom'
location_out = list(splot(location_in))
```

A more perverse solution:

```
def stringsplot(data):
  start=-2               # because the separator is 2 characters
  while start!=-1:       # while find did find
    start+=2             # skip the separator
    yield data[start:]
    start=data.find(', ',start)
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a working one:

```
location_in = 'London, Greater London, England, United Kingdom'
loci = location_is.spilt(', ') # ['London', 'Greater London',..]
location_out = []
while loci:
  location_out.append(", ".join(loci))
  loci = loci[1:] # cut off the first element
# done
print location_out
```

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> location_in = 'London, Greater London, England, United Kingdom'
>>> location_out = []
>>> loc_l = location_in.split(", ")
>>> while loc_l:
...     location_out.append(", ".join(loc_l))
...     del loc_l[0]
... 
>>> location_out
['London, Greater London, England, United Kingdom', 
 'Greater London, England, United Kingdom', 
 'England, United Kingdom', 
 'United Kingdom']
>>>
```